# Can I reduce fixed factors when there is convergence failure in glmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

In my glmer model, there are four variables treated as fixed effects: `A` (categorical, 2 levels), `B` (categorical, 3 level), `C` (categorical, 2 levels), `D` (continuous variable), with `participant` and `item` being as random effects. There is convergence failure even there is only one random effect in this model:

`glmer1 = dv~A*B*C*D+(1|participant)`.

Then I reduced the levels of interaction in the following models, but models still failed to converge (I know that I may not have enough data to support the complexity of these models, but there is nothing I can do now to collect more data):

`glmer2 = dv~(A+B+C+D)^3+(1|participant)`

`glmer3 = dv~(A+B+C+D)^2+(1|participant)`

The only model that converged is the one without interaction:
`glmer4 = dv~A+B+C+D+(1|participant)`

However, because I am primarily interested in the interaction between A, B, and C, can I removed D from fixed effects, which could then allows the following model to converge:

`glmer5 = dv~A*B*C+(1|participant)`

Can anyone tell me whether `glmer5` an appropriate approach or not? Or should I keep the model with all fixed effects but not interaction (`glmer4`)?

Comment: "I know that I may not have enough data to support the complexity of these models" That could mean that you also don't have enough data to answer your research question. In fact, that appears likely. It might be an option to go Bayesian and use rather strong priors (if you have those).

Comment: Thank yo @Roland for your suggestions! I will read more about Bayesian to see if there are other options.

Comment: This package might be useful: https://cran.r-project.org/package=rstanarm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fixed variable D is not needed to answer your research you can remove this variable, especially that you are interested in interaction.

*"There is convergence failure even there is only one random effect in this model"*

You should be careful with removing the random effects, especially if you don't know how is the variance within this variable due to convergence failure. It's important, if the experiment design requires the random effect, you should not remove it just like that.

Comment: Thank you @Jakub for your advice.